# Installing oVirt manager on an ovirt-node

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization, ovirt

Is there a way to install the ovirt manager on to an ovirt-node?  All of the documentation points to getting the manager up and running before setting up a node.  Wondering if it is possible to not have a separate physical system just to run the manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways of doing that (need a full OS, not the ovirt-node distribution though):
1. All-In-One www.ovirt.org/Feature/AllInOne (available today) 
2. Self hosted engine - www.ovirt.org/Features/Self_Hosted_Engine (upcoming)

Comment: Thanks.  Self Hosted Engine is exactly what I was looking for.  I must have missed it when looking through the wiki earlier.  Will have to keep an eye on the development of it.